# Remove top bottom black borders from QuickTime movie

Tags: quicktime, border

[image: image link]

I have the attached QuickTime movie, but it has huge borders. Could you please recommend a program which I can use to get rid of the borders?

Comment: Easiest would be to view the video on a widescreen monitor and maximize the quicktime window. Read more about aspect ratios at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_%28image%29

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tool that may help: [Video Edit Magic](http://www.deskshare.com/Resources/articles/vem_videodim_aspect_dvd.aspx)

Comment: i installed it but it would not run for some reason.